# How to remove unwanted space in column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am seeing unwanted space between children in a column that I don't want. I am to using anything for the free space yet they appear. Please help me get rid of that.
My skills at flutter is beginner so please don't judge me or my lengthy code that can be shortened.

PS: I am not using any widgets to give the extra space yet it appears. IDK what is wrong.

Problem:
[image: UnwantedSpace]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
              child: Text('FOOD & DRINK', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            ),
            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),
            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Restaurant', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),
        
            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Bar', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),
        
            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Coffee', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: Text('SOMTHING TO DO', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            ),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Gym', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Attraction', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Cinema', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Park', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: Text('SHOPPING', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            ),

            Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Toys', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Mall', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Beauty product', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Car seller', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Home and garden', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Dress', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Electronic', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Sport goods', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: Text('SERVICES', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            ),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Hotel', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Beauty services', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Car rental', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

            Row(children: [
              SizedBox(width: 50,),
              Text('Car Washing', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              SizedBox(width: 40,)
        
            ],),

          Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,),

          SizedBox(height: 30,)
            
          ],),
        )
```

Comment: Try speicifying some height in divider

```dart
 Divider(color: Colors.black, indent: 25, endIndent: 25,height:5),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unwanted space you're talking about comes from the [Divider()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) widget.
To get rid of it you should just use containers instead.

```
Column(
                children: [
                 
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "carwashing",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 40,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 800,
                    height: 1,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

I've also changed a few things in your code, instead of doing:

```
Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
```

You can use the [Spacer()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) widget, its only purpose is to tune the spacing between widgets in a Flex container, like Row or Column.

Another thing instead of copy paste the same code over and over again you can wrap it all in a [ListView builder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists) like so:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return Flexible(
        fit: FlexFit.loose,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                ),
                Text(
                  listings[i],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: 800,
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: 20,
  ),
```

And make a list with all the option names outside of the class:

```
List<String> listings = ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add mainAxisAlignment inside the column.
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start

It may solve your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: and remember `CrossAxisAlignment.start` as well for horizontal spacing in Column